# I am a beginner and I'm having trouble compiling a simple program

Tags: mingw

This is the screenshot of the problem I'm having:

[image: This is the screenshot of the problem I'm having]

I downloaded MinGW and still my simple code is not working, I really have no idea what to do.

I already added path of MinGw, and I also deleted path and added it again, but it does not work.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the Problems section you are missing an identifier. In C, functions must have an identifier (a name) after the return type.

Line 2 should be:

```
    int main()
```

If you want to learn more visit https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/print-sentence

Comment: It's Still Not Working

Comment: Your include at the top is something I’ve never heard of. When you are using printf in C, you must include the I/O library. Consider replacing the current include with #include <stdio.h>